# Mysql regexp fails

Tags: mysql, regexp-substr

I'm trying to find any records in table customers where the name does not contain letters. The following is what I am using. When ran, it doesn't return any records found. Would someone point out my mistake, please?

```
    table customers {
    name = Ð•arnings on thÐµ IntÐµrnet from
    }

    SELECT name from customers WHERE name NOT REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]' ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I compare a string using `REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]'`, it matches if *any character* in the string matches a letter in that regexp. The string you show does contain letters like a, r, n, i, g, s. Any one of those is enough to satisfy the REGEXP comparison.

```
mysql> select 'Ð•arnings on thÐµ IntÐµrnet from' REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]' as ok;
+----+
| ok |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The negation `NOT REGEXP` is the same as `NOT (expr REGEXP pattern)`. It simply reverses the result 1 for 0, or 0 for 1.

```
mysql> select 'Ð•arnings on thÐµ IntÐµrnet from' NOT REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]' as ok;
+----+
| ok |
+----+
|  0 |
+----+
```

You said you want to match names that do not contain letters. What I think you mean is that you want to match names that contain any characters that are not letters, which is a different test.

```
mysql> select 'Ð•arnings on thÐµ IntÐµrnet from' REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z]' as ok;
+----+
| ok |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

The characters Ð • µ are not in the range `[a-zA-Z]` and the way to express the complementary range of characters is to use `[^a-zA-Z]`. That is, with the `^` character inside the square brackets, a character would match if it is NOT one of the characters in that range.

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax under the item:

> - [a-dX], [^a-dX]

---

Re your comment:

I tested checking for the characters you mention, including space, apostrophe, dot, and dash:

```
mysql> select 'Mr. Tim O''Toole' regexp '[^a-zA-Z \'.-]' as ok;
+----+
| ok |
+----+
|  0 |
+----+

mysql> select 'Mr. Tim $ O''Toole' regexp '[^a-zA-Z \'.-]' as ok;
+----+
| ok |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

You don't need to put a backslash before the `-`, but it does need to be handled specially:

> To include a literal - character, it must be written first or last.

This is in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I made the change you mentioned and it works. But what I really trying to do is to allow all names that do not have numbers. So a name could have a period, space, apostrophe and a dash, like Mr. Tim O;Toole. To that end, I tried this - [^a-zA-Z.\' ] - andit seems to work as I want. Although  [^a-zA-Z.\'\- ] causes a mysql error. And if I just try yours -  [^a-zA-Z], it says it is OK. Do I need to add those extra characters and, if so, why does the dash cause a failure?

Comment: In case anyone else runs across the hyphen problem, I found it works if it is placed first, like this: [^-a-zA-Z.,\' ]